# How to make python to attempt certain function several times and send me an email if there is an error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to automate a script that I built for ArcSDE data management and GIS Server management. The code does several maintenance jobs and send me an e-mail whether it successes or failed.

I will schedule the code through a window scheduler to run it weekly. When there is an error, possibly due to a user connection, I want to make it re-run the code after time sleep for 24 hours, rather than disconnect users. I want to repeat this process for up to 6 days.

To simplify, I want this:

1) Day 1: run code, send an email about the result if it success. If it fails, time sleep for 24 hours.

2) Day 2: run the code again. Same as day 1

.....

6) Day 6: run the code again. Send an email about the result if it success. If it fails, send an email about the error.

```
try:
    for i in range (5):
        try:
            "What_I_want_to_do_here, including sending an email that it was successful"

        except:
            print ("Failed! Time sleep for a day")
            time.sleep(60*60*24)

except Exception as e:
    exc_tuple = cgitb.text(sys.exc_info())
    e = "[[Error is: " + str(e) +"]]\nDetailed error message: " + str(exc_tuple)
    #send email about the error.
    send_email(sender, mailpwd, recipient, "[Maintenance] Failed", e)
```

My code doesn't send me an email after the sixth failure. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this will run every day and send an email if you succeed or store an error if it fails. On day 6, it will send you an email with all errors of the week. This should do it:

```
day = 1
errors = []
while day < 7:

    # Code for sixth day
    if day == 6:
        for e, exc_tuple in errors:
            e = "[[Error is: " + str(e) +"]]\nDetailed error message: " + str(exc_tuple)
            #send email about the error.
            send_email(sender, mailpwd, recipient, "[Maintenance] Failed", e)

    # Your daily Code
    try:
        "What_I_want_to_do_here, including sending an email that it was successful"
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Failed! Time sleep for a day")
        errors.append(e, cgitb.text(sys.exc_info()))
        time.sleep(60*60*24)
    tries += 1
```

If that's not what you want, try to explain it better.